# Can I append data to an existing BigQuery table from a CSV file using the API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-bigquery

I'm trying to use Google Apps Script to append data into a BigQuery table using the BigQuery API. The data to append is currently CSV format. So far I've found that you can [stream data into BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery) using `tabledata().insertAll()` but it looks like that requires json format and I'm not even convinced that it would do what I need to. Is there a straightforward solution to this that I'm missing? Because I know BigQuery supports appending, and yet everything I'm finding is really focused on loading data into new tables.

**EDIT:**
Sounds like `tabledata().insertAll()` is indeed the right method to use (hopefully). So I converted my file to json instead, but now I'm stuck on how to actually use it. I'm trying to base what I'm doing off of the [reference page for it](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll) but it's still really confusing for me. Currently I am getting a `404` error when I run my code and it hits the `fetch` call. I'm trying to do a URL fetch, maybe that's not how I'm supposed to be doing things? I'm really new to APIs and I'm still figuring out how they work. Here's the code I currently have that's causing this:

```
var tableId = 'users';
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(jsonId);
//I don't know if a blob is the type that I want or not, but I'm trying it
var data = file.getBlob();

var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/PROJECT_ID/datasets/DATASET_ID/tables/tableId/insertAll'
.replace("PROJECT_ID", params.PROJECT_ID)
.replace("DATASET_ID", params.DATASET_ID)
.replace("tableId", tableId);

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
"kind": "bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest",
"skipInvalidRows": 0,
"ignoreUnknownValues": 0,
"rows": [
  {
    "json": data
  }
],
headers: {
  Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
}
});


var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

Comment: You already identified the method, getting the data into the right format is just a matter of parsing the csv and encoding it in JSON, which step are you having problems with? What have you tried already

Comment: So the `insertAll()` method is indeed the one I want? My problem then is finding a decent way to convert the CSV file to json (ideally with Google Apps Script) I guess. Plus actually figuring out how the function call works. I was just really skeptical that this was even the right method that I was looking for.

Comment: OK I think I have my data in json format now (hopefully correctly). From here though, I'm struggling to actually make the call to the API. I can update my question with more details now.

Comment: Google Apps Script can enable the BigQuery API without doing a fetch, you just need to activate it and enable in in the developer's console.Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the most direct from csv to BQ JSON but it's some code that I'm using that should help you on the BigQuery side.

```
var PROJECT_ID = "xxx";
var DATASET_ID = "yyy";
function convertValuesToRows(data) {
  var rows = [];  
  var headers = data[0];

  for (var i = 1, numColumns = data.length; i < numColumns; i++) {
    var row = BigQuery.newTableDataInsertAllRequestRows();
    row.json = data[i].reduce(function(obj, value, index) {
      obj[headers[index]] = value;
      return obj
    }, {});
    rows.push(row);
  }; 
  return rows;
}

function bigqueryInsertData(data, tableName) {
  var insertAllRequest = BigQuery.newTableDataInsertAllRequest();
  insertAllRequest.rows = convertValuesToRows(data);
  var response = BigQuery.Tabledata.insertAll(insertAllRequest, PROJECT_ID, DATASET_ID, tableName);
  if (response.insertErrors) {
    Logger.log(response.insertErrors);
  }
}
```

This allows you to supply any GAS style value matrix (from getValues or indeed [Utilities.parseCsv](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parseCsv(String)))

`convertValuesToRows` will take a 2d array of strings (with headers) and encode it in the format BigQuery needs, e.g.

```
[["H1", "H2", "H3"],
 [1   , 2   , 3   ],
 [4   , 5   , 6   ]];
```

will be added to the insertRows request int he form of key value pairs i.e.

```
[{H1: 1, H2: 2, H3: 3},
 {H1: 4, H2: 5, H3: 6}]
```

You only need to worry about the first representation as that is what you pass into bigQueryInsertData together with the table name you want to feed the data in to (The schema of the table needs to match what you are sending) and the converter function is called from within.

`Utilities.parseCsv` already returns a 2d array of strings so you can basically call `bigQueryInsertData(Utilities.parseCsv(data.getDataAsString()), "myTable")`

Comment: I can't quite tell how to utilize your answer. I'm trying to understand what I'm looking at here but I'm kinda confused. Could you maybe explain what this code is doing a little? Am I somehow parsing the json into individual rows to insert one at a time? And is there documentation for the Scripts version of the API somewhere? All I'm going on is autocompletion in scripts.

Comment: Please see my updated answer, hope that clears things up a bit. Once you enabled the BigQuery API you should be able to use the function as is

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! My code is running without throwing errors and claims to be working successfully, but I haven't seen any data updates actually occurring yet on BigQuery. I figure it probably takes a couple minutes to register the change, but I've been waiting and refreshing with no luck, so it's hard to say yet if everything's working. Any insight on what the problem would be if my code isn't complaining and yet isn't actually doing its job? I've logged the progress so I see that your functions are executing... Idk maybe in an hour BigQuery will show it really did work.

Comment: Inserts should be querieable immediately, did you check the execution log to see if there were any insert errors?

Comment: No errors, plus I added more log statements to make sure things were actually executing (they are), hence my confusion...

Comment: Try putting breakpoints and running the script in debug mode. I suspect the issue is one of the following: csv isn't parsed correctly or empty, data has wrong schema, issues with authorization in BigQuery. does the parsed csv contain the data you expect? does the request object match the layout of your table?

Comment: The only potential issue I can find is that the schema in the json rows are coming out in the wrong order, from the line in `convertValuesToRows()` that defines `row.json` but to be honest that's the one part of the code where I don't fully understand what's going on. How could it be switching the order? The order in `headers` is as expected... But also why isn't it then throwing a schema error? The CSV definitely isn't empty, when I look at the request, the data is there. And I'm also not getting any authorization errors... it's really confusing. Silent errors are the most difficult to find.

Comment: It's not that, rows is a list of dictionaries, which are unordered. convertValuesToRows takes the first row as headers and goes through each subsequent row assigning the value to the key defined by the header. Perhaps you can provide an example csv and schema where this happens?

Comment: Ah ok I didn't realize it was a dict. The CSV is from a Google Analytics report in Sheets. The schema originally have `ga:`on the front but I strip it in the `headers` variable using `for(var i=0; i<headers.length; i++){headers[i] = headers[i].substr(3);}` and it seems to have worked.

Comment: I'm now thinking it's a problem with BigQuery though. Refreshing it again this morning, the table preview showed 10x the entries of what I was trying to accomplish (I probably ran it 10 times) but then as soon as I click away and return to the page, the table looks empty again. Queries on it yesterday showed 0 records but queries today return results even when the preview shows 0 records. Thanks for all the stress, BigQuery... So I guess it does just take (a long) time for BQ to sync the tables with the load jobs. Thank you so much for all of your help!!!

Comment: Glad it worked in the end. The preview can indeed lag a bit, I'm surprised the actual population took so long. If this helped you please accept the answer, thanks.